# Выбрать 1-ю и/или 2-ю у ячейку таблицы, у которой встречается определенный класс средствами CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, list

Ниже привел пример кода, через `:child` выбрать не получается – класс ищется у первой ячейки, а не первой с таким классом:

```css
tr td.red:first-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="red">1</td>
        <td class="red">1</td>
        <td class="red">1</td>
      </tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="red">1</td>
      <td class="red">1</td>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет, селектора для выбора n-ного элемента по определенному **классу** не существует. По типу элемента - можно. По классу - нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание, что ваша разметка таблицы невалидна. Ячейки `td` не могут быть у `tbody` без `tr`. Подробнее про селектор можно перевести [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class). Если вкратце, то `+ .red` означает, что следующая ячейка с `class="red"` после ячейки без класса red `:not(.red)` будет закрашена красным.

```css
.red:first-child, :not(.red) + .red {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="red">1</td>
        <td class="red">1</td>
        <td class="red">1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="red">1</td>
        <td class="red">1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: смысл выбрать любую определенную ячейку а не только первую, вообще возможно ли это

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов так какую вам ячейку надо выбрать? Решение именно под вашу формулировку вопроса. Если все, то .red {} или :not(.red) ~ .red {}

Comment: Или все кроме последних .red:not(:last-child) {}. Переформулируйте пожалуйста конкретнее задачу

Comment: изменил сам заголовок вопроса, хочу именно привязаться к определенной ячейке, с классом red. например второй, третьей

Comment: так не получится если это тот же элемент и классы могут быть не у всех ячеек. Хотя, наверно тут через JS можно попробовать, но точно не стилями

Answer (score 0):

```
td.red:nth-of-type(1) // или 2 или 3 и тд, можно через запятую
```

или

```
td.red:first-of-type
td.red:last-of-type
```

если я конечно правильно вопрос понял